# Что писать если отсутствует аргумент требуемый формальному параметру?

Tags: c#

Как правильно вводить данные в аргумент Метода Func в массив numbers что бы метод выполнялся?

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            void Func(int[] numbers,int L, int R)
            {
                int  middle, I, J, F, Z;
                
                I = L; J = R;
                middle = (L + R) / 2;
                do
                {
                    do
                    {
                        F = 0;
                        if (numbers[I] < numbers[middle]) F = -1;
                        if (numbers[I] > numbers[middle]) F = 1;
                        if (F > 0) I = I + 1;
                        Console.WriteLine(I);

                    }
                    while
                    (F < 0);
                    do
                    {
                        F = 0;
                        if (numbers[J] < numbers[middle]) F = -1;
                        if (numbers[J] > numbers[middle]) F = 1;
                        if (F > 0) J = J + 1;
                        Console.WriteLine(J);
                    }
                    while
                    (F < 0);
                    if  (I <= J)
                    { 
                        Z = numbers[I]; numbers[I] = numbers[J]; numbers[J] = Z;
                    }
                }
                while
                (I <= J);
                if (L < J) Func(numbers, L, J);
                 else if (I < R) Func(numbers, I, R);
            }
            Func(numbers,15, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это массив целых чисел.

Comment: Да это понятно, но при передаче возникает исключение я все перевел с алгоритмичного языка на шарп, и не понимаю какие данные нужно вставлять что бы было валидно

Comment: Создайте массив: `var numbers = new int[] { тут числа };`

Comment: Все это я уже сделал, выкидывает исключение то что попытка обращения к элементу массива или коллекции с индексом, который находится вне границ, я думаю что делаю что то не так

Comment: Либо массив сделать больше, либо границы - меньше.

Comment: Нет, не сделали. В показанном коде этого нет. Покажите _настоящий_ код.

Comment: https://ideone.com/MR6xlQ Вот, в Visual Studio ошибки не выпадают как здесь, там все верно и код компилируется( но с исключением как и писал выше)

Comment: Почему вы там приводите один код, а здесь - другой?

Comment: Ну вы дали совет как правильно сделать рефакторинг, я сделал, поэтому, я писал при исключение, если создавать массив то исключение не будет вылезать, потому что массив будет cуществовать в нужном формате

Comment: L это левая граница, R это правая граница. R> L. Вы вводите наоборот.

Comment: Совет по именованию: [называйте](https://habr.com/ru/post/26077/) переменные с маленькой буквы, а методы и свойства с большой, тогда не будет путаницы, и всем будет понятен ваш код.

Comment: Вы использовали [локальную функцию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) в своём коде. Эта фича появилась в C# 7.0. Сайт ideone имеет более старую версию языка/компилятора, поэтому на нём невозможно запустить этот код.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки в `ideone.com` сыпятся потому что у тебя метод `Func` внутри метода `Main`.

Банальная проверка аргументов с выдачей в консоль все показывает.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1 {

    class Program {

        private static void Main (string[] args) {
            Func(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 5, 2);
        }

        private static void Func (int[] numbers, int l, int r) {
            if (l < 0 || l >= numbers.Length) {
                Console.WriteLine("Fail. L["+l+"] is out of numbers array lenght["+numbers.Length+"]");
                return;
            }
            if (r < 0 || r >= numbers.Length) {
                Console.WriteLine("Fail. R["+r+"] is out of numbers array lenght["+numbers.Length+"]");
                return;
            }
            // Нет смысла их объявлять через запятую без значений, если в следующей же строчке ты присваиваешь им всем значения. 
            int Middle = (l+r)/2;
            int I = l;
            int J = r;
            // в do-whilr (I <= J) нет смысла.
            // в конце этого цикла if с тем-же условием которое меняет их местами и оно на 1 раз, не подразумевающее цикличность.
            // А если они ровны цикл безконечен.

            // в do-whilr (F < 0) для I нет смысла.
            // if numbers[I] < numbers[Middle] или если ==(не обрабатывается), ничего не меняет и происходит бесконечный цикла.
            // только (numbers[I] > numbers[Middle]) увеличива I на 1 и выходит из цикла.
            if (numbers[I] > numbers[Middle])
                I++;
            // c J тоже самое.
            if (numbers[J] > numbers[Middle])
                J++;
            // какой смыл менять их местами если I == J? 
            // это один и то-же индекс. только <.
            if (I < J) {
                int Temp = numbers[I];
                numbers[I] = numbers[J];
                numbers[J] = Temp;
            }
            if (l < J)
                Func(numbers, l, J);
            else if (I < r)
                Func(numbers, I, r);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Fail. L[5] is out of numbers array lenght[3]
```

Это не все ошибки. Обратил внимание только на поверхностное безумие. Вряд ли эта рекурсивная сортировка работает.

Comment: спасибо большое!!!!